I drove with my Parking Brake on for 30 minutes
I forgot to release the parking brake.
It was indicated but the light is always on even if I know the brake is off (shotty work on the car before it was mine). Anyway when I was driving during the last 10 minutes the brake lost resistance and only started working when pushed to the floor.
Sitting in the parking lot starting it up and driving slightly, resistance seems to have come back.
My car is a 1999 Toyota Camry CE. What are the chances that ruined my brakes, or did they just need a rest?
